# Cases where RLT/SDP relaxation does not work well with standard quadratic optimization

Tags: quadratic-programming, nonconvex-programming, mosek, yalmip, reformulation-linearization

**(For people who don't know what RLT is)**: I am maximizing an indefinite quadratic function over a standard simplex, i.e., *the standard quadratic optimization problem.* A well-known approach is to relax the problem by convexifying the objective function, i.e., instead of $\max \sum_{i} \sum_{j} P_{ij} x_i x_j$ for some symmetric $P$ we maximize the linear function $\max \sum_{i} \sum_{j} P_{ij} X_{ij}$ for some symmetric matrix variable $X$ (assumption is $X = xx^\top$, although we cannot constrain this, so the relaxation follows as we are not imposing such strict equality). We also take each constraint $a_i^\top x - b_i \leq 0$, multiply with each other, add the constraint $(a_i^\top x - b_i) (a_j^\top x - b_j) \geq 0 $ and replace every $x_i x_j$ term with $X_{ij}$. This is the RLT relaxation. If we also add the SDP constraint $X - xx \succeq 0$, this tightens the relaxation. Let's call this method the RLT/SDP approximation.

**(Question for the people who already know RLT):** I made numerical experiments, where I generate a symmetric matrix $P$ randomly, and then apply RLT/SDP relaxation. The results are crazy-good, almost all of the time I get globally optimum upper bounds (and when I plug the optimized $x$, it also gives amazing lower bounds). I am now thinking, every beautiful thing has an ugly truth as well. Can you please let me know an adversarial way to design a $P$, such that the RLT/SDP relaxation is not that good?

**(Matlab Code Below -- uses YALMIP, CPLEX, and MOSEK):**

```
P = rand(20); P = P - tril(P,-1) + triu(P,1)'; %generate random symmetric matrix (change 20 to any number)
n = size(P,1);
%CPLEX GLOBAL OPTIM BELOW
x = sdpvar(n,1);
obj = x'*P*x;
constraints = [x >= 0, sum(x) == 1];
sol = optimize(constraints, -obj, sdpsettings('solver', 'cplex', 'cplex.optimalitytarget',3));
value(obj); %global optimum value
%RLT RELAXATION BELOW!
X = sdpvar(n); %matrix variable
x = sdpvar(n,1); %original variable
obj2 = P(:)'*X(:); %RLT objective
constraints2 = [x>=0, sum(x) == 1, sum(X,2) == x, X(:) >= 0, [X, x; x', 1] >= 0]; %RLT/SDP system
sol2 = optimize(constraints2, -obj2, sdpsettings('solver', 'mosek')); %optimize
value(obj2) %wow!
```

Comment: I don't have a mathematical argument for it, but computational experience is that randomly-generated instances are often easy to solve, in most contexts. In your case, I would try with instances from [QPLIB](http://qplib.zib.de/).

Comment: Nice, I agree! But these files don't store the matrix $P$ and it will be hard for me to reproduce these examples.

Comment: You can download them in `.qplib` fromat, which has the Q matrix in COO format. Shouldn't be too hard to parse.
Or in `.lp` format, which you can feed to CPLEX directly.
In fact, instance [QPLIB_0018](http://qplib.zib.de/lp/QPLIB_0018.lp) has exactly the form you are considering.

Comment: Yes, I parsed, thank you! I am trying now.

Comment: Well, RLT/SDP is still always globally optimal.  I need adversarially designed cases.

Comment: Try replacing sum(x) ==1 with 1 >= x. You'll see things change big time.

Comment: And I mean BIIIIIIIIIIG time.

Comment: Do you mean sum(x)<=1 as a constraint?

Comment: No, I mean what I wrote.  constraints = [1 >= x >= 0];  Try it,  BTW, there is nothing special about the choice of "1"; it just makes the problem bounded in the absence of the sum(x) == 1 constraint.

Comment: Thanks so much for this suggestion. But I think by adding auxiliary redundant constraints we can do worse and worse. I am looking for a theoretical answer — more like a structure for the indefinite quadratic matrix such that the rlt sdp approximatikn is weak.

Comment: I made a modification to your example which makes the SDP very non-optimal. I leave the theoretical explanation, if any, to someone else.I played around some with alternate P matrices, but that didn't seem to do much without modifying the constraints.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Thanks so much for trying this :) I observe that if we add a concave term to the objective function, then this may worsen the quality of relaxation as the second term will not have the matrix variable in it.